# How to re-render component on going back using back button in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

If I go from home screen to product details screen and then to cart screen then the state update works fine but from cart screen if I add items or remove items and then navigate back to product details or home screen then state is not updated why so?  See vudeo link below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AjrFMAXBs9Gzc5Onbm1uf-eW9gFfHxMU/view?usp=sharing

I am using redux but even if redux store state is updated still it doesn't render component with updated state why so?

I am think of using react navigation events but I am getting error why so? How to solve the problem? is this redux problem or react navigation problem? Does component re - render when navigated back to previous screen?

If I refresh the emulator screen then state is updated and displayed properly why does this happen?

I want to re render Home component when focused back but getting error. why so?

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

home.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Button
} from 'react-native';
import Product from '../product/product';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import axios from 'axios';

export const Home = (props) => {

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            const unsubscribe = FetchCategoryData();

            return () => unsubscribe();
        }, [])
    );

    const FetchCategoryData = () => {

        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/categories`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("All categories: ", res.data.data);

                setCategories([...res.data.data]);

                console.log("useeffect categories",categories)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log("Error: ", error))
    }

    return(
        <ScrollView style={styles.root}>
            <View style={{marginTop: 15, marginLeft: 15, marginBottom: 15}}> 
                <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={styles.container}>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <View style={{marginRight: 15}}>
                            <Image source={require('../../assets/img/fruits.jpg')} style={{width: 325, height: 200, borderRadius: 10}}/>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <View style={{marginRight: 15}}>
                            <Image source={require('../../assets/img/grocery.jpg')} style={{width: 325, height: 200, borderRadius: 10}}/>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <View style={{marginRight: 15}}>
                            <Image source={require('../../assets/img/fruits.jpg')} style={{width: 325, height: 200, borderRadius: 10}}/>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
            {categories && categories.length > 0 ? categories.map(val => <CategoryList key={val._id} category={val.name} navigation={props.navigation}/>) : null}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Check out [reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#re-rendering-screen-with-the-useisfocused-hook).

In short, using

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();
```

somewhere in your component, will force a rerender, every time window is focused or unfocused.

> The useIsFocused hook will cause our component to re-render when we focus and unfocus a screen. Using this hook component may introduce unnecessary component re-renders as a screen comes in and out of focus. This could cause issues depending on the type of action we're calling on focusing. Hence we recommend to use this hook only if you need to trigger a re-render. For side-effects such as subscribing to events or fetching data, use the methods described above.

Comment: You made my day, @aurelia.

Comment: woow, thank you so much for this answer, here in 2023, it's still worthy, Kudos..

Answer (score 3):

React Navigation doesn't re-render screens when going back. This is so that your screens don't have to re-fetch their data or display a loading indicator every time you navigate. If you would like to perform some update when a screen, try reading [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/navigation-prop.html#addlistener---subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle).

In short, React Navigation lets you subscribe to navigation events such as when a screen has just been focused:

```js
export default class Screen extends Component {

    navigationSubscription;

    componentDidMount() {
        // Fetch initial data and add navigation listener
        // ...

        this.navigationSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.onFocus);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.navigationSubscription.remove();
    }

    // This function will be called everytime this screen is shown
    onFocus = (payload) => {
        console.log(payload);
        // You can then check for updates here
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>I'm a screen</Text>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is useFocusEffect not working I am using react navigation v5