# React Native not re-rendering screen on goBack()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am currently developing a mobile app using React Native and I'm having this problem.
I have two screens: SiteScreen and FormScreen. First one displays site's info and the second one is a form to rate the site.
So when I fill the form and I send it to my API I update the info of the site and I want it to be updated in SiteScreen so user can see it, but it does not. I can print it in FormScreen updated but not in the other screen

I tried with this first function that's called when send button is pressed

```
    const saveChanges = () => {
        if (Object.keys(selectedValues).length === 0)
            setHasError(true);
        else {
            // Código para guardar los cambios
            console.log('Changes saved: ', selectedValues);
            site.nombre = "(Rated)";
            navigation.setParams({ site: site });
            navigation.goBack();
        }
    }
```

and I managed to make it work by doing this in SiteScreen:

```
    const site = route.params.site;
    const [, setState] = useState(false);
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            console.log("Focused")
            console.log("Nombre en site: " + site.nombre)
            setState(prev => !prev);
            return () => { };
        }, [])
    );
```

But this is the real function that I have to use to make the request and what i've done doesn't work with async functions idk why

```
     const saveChangesAsync = async () => {
        if (Object.keys(selectedValues).length === 0)
            setHasError(true);
        else {
            const response = await sendRating(selectedValues, site, user!._id);
            if (response.success && "newPlace" in response) {
                response.newPlace.nombre = "(Rated)";
                console.log("Nombre en form: " + response.newPlace.nombre)
                navigation.setParams({ site: response.newPlace });
                setTimeout(() => {
                    navigation.goBack();
                }, 100);
            }
            else
                console.log(response.message)
        }
    }
```

Please someone help me. I've been too much time struggling with this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362589/how-to-re-render-component-on-going-back-using-back-button-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `navigate` instead of `goBack` to pass back parameters. This will update route params in a previous screen. Something like this:

```
navigation.navigate({
  name: 'Site',
  params: { site: response.newPlace },
  merge: true,
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create a bad user experience? since if the user later, being in SiteScreen, goes back, he will return to FormScreen and then to SiteScreen again(?)

Comment: No, if the screen is already in the stack's history, it'll go back to that screen.